Derivative of a curve in the tangent space paired with a curve in the cotangent space
Let $M$ be a manifold, $x_t : \mathbb{R} \to M$ a smooth curve on $M$. Then we consider curves $y_t, \theta_t$ over the curve $x_t$ in the tangent space and cotangent space respectively. That is $y_t : \mathbb{R} \to TM$, $\theta_t : \mathbb{R} \to T^* M$ and
$$\pi_{TM}(y_t) = x_t = \pi_{T^*M}(\theta_t).$$
Then we can write down the pairing
$$\theta_t(y_t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}.$$
My question is what is the intrinsic (coordinate-free) representation of the time derivative of this function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Obviously, we can write down the derivative in coordinates. I think also if we have a metric and take the Levi-Cevita connection, we have the formula that
$$\frac{d}{dt} \theta_t(y_t) = \Big(\frac{D}{dt} \theta_t\Big)(y_t) + \theta_t\Big(\frac{D}{dt} y_t\Big).$$
This uses extraneous structure though, as the left-hand side is metric independent and the right-hand side is not manifestly so. Is there a neat way to write this derivative without using coordinates or connections?

Why do you need a metric and the Levi-Civita connection? Any connection on $TM$ (and the corresponding dual connection on $T^*M$) should give the identical formula. It seems hopeless to write down a coordinate-free formula without a connection; how else can you differentiate sections of a vector bundle, even over a curve?

@TedShifrin You can differentiate vector fields along integral curves to compute a linearization by taking the differential of the vector field. This allows you to consider linearizations of vector fields without a connection. The object I’m looking at (the time derivative of the pairing) is independent of any connection so I was hoping for an expression for it that is also independent of a connection. Also one can certainly consider arbitrary connections too, though I don’t have any motivation to in my current setting.

What do you mean by the differential of a vector field (unless $M$ is embedded in a vector space)? There’s an intrinsic derivative (which I’ve discussed in several posts on MSE) defined at the zeroes of the vector field, but definitely not more generally.

@TedShifrin I can't find many resources on this (though it is discussed briefly in Michor, Topics in Diff. Geo., 8.19), but I wrote it up in here. This should be a generalization of the notion you give of an intrinsic derivative about a 0. The point is that for a vector field $V : M \to TM$ there is a "natural lift" $L : TM \to TTM$ that is a vector field on $TM$. Further $L = \kappa \circ TV$, where $TV$ is the differential of $V$ and $\kappa$ is the "canonical flip".
